# Cannot install Ionic-Native File plugin

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I have an Ionic 3 project to which I am trying add Ionic Native File plugin, using the command:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
L:\MyTrials\test\ionic\locations-app>ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file --save
x Running command - failed!
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file

    --save (exit code 1):

    Error: Failed to fetch plugin file:node_modules\cordova-plugin-file via
    registry.
    Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is
    incorrect.
    Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
    Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
    npm ERR! Could not install from "node_modules\cordova-plugin-file" as it
    does not contain a package.json file.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!
    C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-09-21T05_16_31_940Z-debug.log
```

I have already tried other command such as:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
```

and

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file --nofetch
```

but I am basically getting the same error.

My internet connection is fine and I ran these commands as Administrator.

It seems that only the File plugin may be having these issues. I could install the Ionic Native Datepicker plugin without any issues.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you remove the plugin `ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-file` first and also folder in `node_modules\cordova-plugin-file` then again install see what happens.

Comment: @amin arghavani: Thanks for the reply! Running the command:
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-file gave the below output:
Error: Plugin "cordova-plugin-file" is not present in the project. See
`cordova plugin list`.
In node_modules I only found a shortcut link to cordova-plugu-file that simply pointed to the node_modules folder. I've now deleted it.
Next I tried adding cordova-plugin-file using ionic - again I've got the same above error.
Also not sure why is it that this plugin has no package.json file...

Comment: @aminarghavani: In addition to my previous comment, I've also found that there is a reference to cordova-plugin-file in my ionic project's package.json file. I've deleted this entry and tried to add cordova-plugin-file via the ionic command. This time the command ran successfully without issues! Thank you for helping me on this!!

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen in the question's comments, with the help of @amin arghavani, doing the following resolved the issue:

1. Remove the plugin if its already installed: `ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-file`
   In my case this plugin was never installed so I got the same message as an error.
2. Check if a folder for the plugin is present under the project's `node_modules` folder.
   In my case I actually found a shortcut link named after the plugin (`cordova-plugin-file`) which I've deleted.
3. Check if plugin is included in the project's `package.json` as a dependency or developer dependency.
   In my case I found the reference to `cordova-plugin-file` under dependencies (which I deleted and saved) in `package.json`.
4. Add the cordova component again from commandline which worked for me.